# Echoing a PHP String

Tags: php, css

Ok I've got PHP to successfully open and read the contents of a directory containing a number of images.  I pass all of this data into an array, sort the results and finally iterate over all of the images so that it gives me a sting which I then echo onto the html page.  In this string I set the css class for each div so that when the page renders each div is displayed correctly.

My question is to do with the actual PHP setting the class of each div.  Basically I have two classes that I apply to each div depending on what number they are.  For example in the first horizontal row, the 1st to 3rd div gets the class of `.box` so as to set a `margin-right:10px;` and the 4th get's it's own class of `.box last` which sets `margin-right:0px;`.

So what I wanted to ask was is there way of writing some logic to tell the PHP code to apply one class for the 1st to 3rd divs and a separate class for every 4th div for each row?Effectively the first three divs in the row get on class and the fourth div in each row gets another?

```
<?php 
$dir = "images/"; 

$images = array();

$returnstr = "";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while ( false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".."){
            $images[] = $entry;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

natsort($images);

$newArray = array_values($images);

foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    $returnstr .= '<li class="box">';
    $returnstr .= '<a href="#" name="" class="thumb" id="' . $key . '"><img src="'. $dir . '/' . $value . '"/></a>';
    $returnstr .= '</li>';
}

?>
```

This is the CSS for the 1st - 3rd divs...

```
.box {

float: left;
/*margin-right:10.5px;*/
margin-right:10px;
/*width: 92px;
height: 92px; */
width: 232.5px;
height:150px;
/*height: 232px; */
/*background-color: #999;
border: 1px solid*/
margin-bottom: 10px;  
list-style: none;  
}
```

... and the CSS for every 4th div in the grid

```
.box.last {
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

This is the html I trying to atchieve.

```
<li class="box">
  <a href="#" name="cap1" class="thumb" id=""><img src="images/1.jpg"/></a>
</li>

<li class="box">
  <a href="#" name="cap2" class="thumb" id=""><img src="images/2.jpg"/></a>
</li>

<li class="box">
  <a href="#" name="cap3" class="thumb" id=""><img src="images/3.jpg"/></a>
</li>

<li class="box last">
  <a href="#" name="cap4" class="thumb" id=""><img src="images/4.jpg"/></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Remove everything that doesn't matter, tell us exactly but with less words, what you tried and how you failed. This question is way too long!

Comment: This can be effectively done on the client side, with no additional CSS, using `:nth-child()`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I don't think op wants it for just the (n)th child. They want it for every nth child, right?

Comment: @shortstuffsushi: `:nth-child(4n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [modulus operator, %](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), along with an integer that you increment each time through the loop.  Simple example:

```
<?php

$n = 0;
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    $n++;
    if($n > 0 && ($n % 4) === 0){
        $everyFourthRowCss = " last";
    } else {
        $everyFourthRowCss = "";
    }
    $returnstr .= "<li class='box{$everyFourthRowCss}'>";
    $returnstr .= '<a href="#" name="" class="thumb" id="' . $key . '"><img src="'. $dir . '/' . $value . '"/></a>';
    $returnstr .= '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Hi @JoshuaBeall thanks for your answer, though one thing I need to change was the &n to $n in the if else statement.  Apart from that, works like a charm!

Comment: @user1563944 typo on my part, sorry about that!  I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a `.last` class with php, you could use a css selector to give special margin to the fourth `<li>` element(s) like so:

```
li.box:nth-child(4){
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Which would apply to any `<li>` that is the 4th child of its parent container

Comment: but be careful for browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Seems like quite a useful site

Answer (score 0):

You need to use modulos, something like :

```
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    $returnstr .= '<li class="box';
    if (($key > 0) && (($key % 4) == 0)) {
        $returnstr .= ' last';
    }
    $returnstr .= '">';
    $returnstr .= '<a href="#" name="" class="thumb" id="' . $key . '"><img src="'. $dir . '/' . $value . '"/></a>';
    $returnstr .= '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ninsuo I'm sure your way works but I just couldn't get my head around that modulos stuff

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing your `foreach` loop to:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
  $last_class = ($i == 4) ? ' last' : '' ;
  $returnstr .= '<li class="box' . $last_class . '">';
  $returnstr .= '<a href="#" name="" class="thumb" id="' . $key . '"><img src="'. $dir . '/' . $value . '"/></a>';
  $returnstr .= '</li>';
  $i++;
}
```

This way, regardless what `$key` is (in the case of an associative array), you still only apply this to the fourth item.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $newArray as $key => $value ) {
    if( $key % 4 == 0 ) {
        $returnstr .= '<li class="box last">';
    } else {
        $returnstr .= '<li class="box">';
    }
}
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

This might be dirty, but you could simply use a counter as follows:

```
 $counter = 1;
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($counter==4) {
        $returnstr .= '<li class="last">';
    }
    else
    {
        $returnstr .= '<li class="box">';
    }
    $returnstr .= '<a href="#" name="" class="thumb" id="' . $key . '"><img src="'. $dir . '/' . $value . '"/></a>';
    $returnstr .= '</li>';

    $counter++;
}
```

It should do the trick.